# How can I execute Enable-PnpDevice as Administrator in a Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-10, administrator, runas

I'm trying to automate the task of enabling and disabling my laptop's integrated graphics adapter using the `Enable-PnpDevice` and `Disable-PnpDevice` Powershell commands.
I'm using Windows 10 and I have Powershell 7.0.2

This is what I have so far:

```
$Device = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*HD Graphics*"
$DeviceID = $Device.InstanceId
$Status = $Device.Status

If ($Status -eq 'Error') {
    runas /user:kato "Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $DeviceID -confirm:$false"
} Else {
    runas /user:kato "Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $DeviceID -confirm:$false"
}
```

My account has administrator permissions, but when the script uses `runas` like so:

```
runas /user:kato "Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $DeviceID -confirm:$false"
```

I get the following error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0416&SUBSYS_171D1043&REV_06\3&11583659&0&10 -confirm:False
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I run the `Enable-PnpDevice` in an administrator Powershell session the command works as it should.

I've seen some answers on SO that talk about using `runas` to execute programs and scripts, but it is not working in this scenario or I'm doing something wrong.

Is there an alternative or better way to execute `Enable-PnpDevice` and `Disable-PnpDevice` as administrator?

Comment: `runas` runs a process, not a powershell script. You would need to do `runas /user:kato powershell.exe -Command { Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $DeviceID -confirm:$false }`

Comment: But a better way would probably be to run the initial script as admin to begin with.

Comment: `runas` won't request elevation for you, but you can use `Start-Process` with `-Verb 'runas'` to request elevation. (And before you ask, no, you can't automatically bypass the UAC prompt.)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to disable then enable a device using the following (quick and dirty) code in a power shell script (ps1) file. It runs as jobs and the script **assumes the success** of these jobs and for that reason **it fails apx 0.1%** of the runs. But that´s okay for my need.

The final *Start-Sleep -s 5* is just so I can see that the script ran.

First run the *Get-PnpDevice* command in power shell and find the name of the device you want to enable or disable. In this case it´s "Intel(R) UHD Graphics*" - *note the * wildcard and the end of the string*

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Intel(R) UHD Graphics*" | Disable-PnpDevice -AsJob
Start-Sleep -s 2
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Intel(R) UHD Graphics*" | Enable-PnpDevice -AsJob
Start-Sleep -s 5
```

To run the code as admin. I created a shortcut to %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\temp\DisableEnable Intel display.ps1"
In the shortcut properties click Advances and select "Run as administrator"